# I have Multiple csv files.Each csv file contains multiple tables with multiple headers.How to get the table its header contains given specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, datatables

I have multiple csv files (4000) in one folder.  Each csv files have the data like below. Data length, the rows of the headers and number of headers in different lines in each csv file might be different.  There are multiple tables with the headers and these table all starts with the same column "a". I want to get the table that its header contains "apple" and with the values.

Input

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i           
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9           
a   b1  c1  d1  e1  f1  g1                  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7                   
a   b2  c2  d2  e2  f2  g2  h2  i2  k2  l2  
3   5   6   7   3   4   5   6   7   7   0   
a   b3  d3  e3  g23 t4  apple   r4  w2  r5  t6  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   1   1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   11  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   12  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   13  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   14  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   15  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   16  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   17  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   18  1   2
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i           
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Final Output

```
a   b3  d3  e3  g23 t4  apple   r4  w2  r5  t6
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   1   1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   11  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   12  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   13  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   14  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   15  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   16  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   17  1   2
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   18  1   2
```

Comment: What do you mean by each csv file containing multiple tables?

Comment: each csv file contains have input data as above (input) . Multiple Tables : The input file contains multiple headers with the values. Each headers and its values are independent. They are different parameters and measurements.

Comment: Is your input data an example of a single file, with headers below unrelated values belonging to other headers? Or each row of headers would be a separate file?

Comment: Yes, input data is an example file with headers below unrelated values belonging to other headers.

Comment: Are header lines cleanly distinguishable from value lines? Like in your example all the values are numbers and the headers have letters in them. Is something like that true for every file?

If not it will be hard to distinguish a header line from a value line.

Comment: All the  headers are from the letters but the values might be number or text format.

Comment: Ok, well each header line starts with a header that's just `a`. We could determine header lines based on that, unless any of the values are going to be just `a`. Could that be the case?

Comment: First column header name is same for each line and values are different than the header name and it is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the information I got, you'll have to manually loop through each row in each file until you find a row whose first column is just `a` *and* contains a column `apple`. From there you know that's the right headers, so you start storing that line and the value lines after in some way. The next time you see a row whose first column is just `a`, you know you've reached new headers.

pandas probably can't do this directly, so you'll have to do some manual string interpolation.

```
buffer = ''
with open('filename') as f:
    found_apple = False
    for row in f:
        # if a row starts with 'a,' it's a header row
        has_a = row.startswith('a,')
        if found_apple:
            # if the row is a header row, we're done with the table and should wrap up
            if has_a:
                break
            # else it's a row that should be part of our output, so store it in a buffer
            buffer += row # row will already have the \n
        elif not has_a:
            # we aren't ready to look at values, and this row isn't a header row, so skip it
            continue
        elif 'apple' in row:
            # you might have to tweak this if there are headers that *contain* 'apple' but aren't the header you're looking for
            # we've found the start of the table we want, we're ready to start storing the value rows
            found_apple = True
            buffer += row

# buffer will be the table you want, as a string
# example:

# """a,apple
# 1,2"""

# if that's all you need, you can simply output buffer

# if you wanted to do other pandas stuff with that table, you can now pass buffer to pandas
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
table = pd.read(StringIO(buffer))
```

Let me know if there's any part you don't understand.

Edit: to loop every file in a dir just wrap the `with` with another loop:

```
import os
buffer = ''
for filename in os.listdir():
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        continue
    with open(filename) as f:
        ...
    if buffer is not '':
        break

# buffer will be the table you want, as a string
```

Comment: It worked well after i remove `if buffer is not '':` Thank you very much.